# How to validate if server has private interface in Ansible Playbook

Tags: regex, ansible

Ansible-playbook should have specific tasks if the server has private network interface 10.x.x.x.

I am thinkig of using the facts variable `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`. It looks like that:

```
    "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
        "10.1.2.3", 
        "some.public.network.interface"
    ]
```

It works when I define the exact IP address in condition, i.e:

```
- name: foo
  foo: bar
  when: '"10.1.2.3" in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'
```

But it does not work when I try to use any regex. I tried regex like:

```
10.*
10.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
10\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

In each case I get `"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"`

How do I write a correct regex or is there any other way to determine if server has private interface 10.x.x.x?

Comment: Check [ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ipaddr filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html).

I guess you are interested in public/private filter. From the documentation:

```
You can check if IP addresses or network ranges are 
accessible on a public Internet, or if they are in private 
networks:

# {{ test_list | ipaddr('public') }}
['192.24.2.1', '2001:db8:32c:faad::/64']

# {{ test_list | ipaddr('private') }}
['192.168.32.0/24', 'fe80::100/10']
```